# How to find or recreate missing RSS feeds folder on outlook.office365.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

When I connect to the Microsoft's cloud web using a web browser:

**outlook.office365.com**

I do not see a folder `RSS Feeds` under my e-mail account. The same happens when I connect using Outlook 2013 desktop app.
However other colleagues can see this folder both using web browser and Outlook 2013.

How to recreate this folder, so that I can use it, on my outlook.office365.com account?